# Free options for viewing/hosting multiple Swagger/OpenAPI files?

Tags: web

Requirements:

- Sidebar with search
- Host multiple swagger/openapi files at the same time
- "Try it out" button to hit the api live

I'm looking for a free product that will do these things or something that can be easily modified.

- SwaggerUI - can only view one swagger file at a time, no search/sidebar
- ReDoc - no try it out button, can only view one document at a time
- RapiDoc - can only view one swagger file at a time, no search/sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RapiDoc](https://mrin9.github.io/RapiDoc/) Author here

I think RapiDoc can very well do what you are looking for. It is a CustomElement / WebComponent that can be added any number of times inside an HTML therefore allowing you to show multiple docs at the same time

For instance look at the following implementation 
https://www.northbricks.io/apis
though it seems like a single unified document but it is made up of many micro-services each having its own openApi spec
View source of the above html to see how they have achieved it

Comment: Any chance you'll add something like https://github.com/Cimpress/swagger-ui-cimpress Just wondering haha I really like the way it looks.

Comment: checkout this issue https://github.com/mrin9/RapiDoc/issues/59 you should get some idea on future plans